# "Vector erase iterator outside range" error

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to run the below example provided in book to test the functionality, but getting an error regarding saying "Vector erase iterator outside range". I couldn't figure out what that means.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    using MyVector = vector<int>;
    MyVector newVector = { 0,1,2 };
    newVector.push_back(3);
    newVector.push_back(4);

    MyVector::const_iterator iter = newVector.cbegin() + 1;
    newVector.insert(iter, 5);
    newVector.erase(iter);

    for (auto iter = newVector.begin(); iter != newVector.end(); ++iter) {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you put the error message into Google and read the results?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/ about iterator validity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `newVector.insert(iter, 5)`, `iter` is not valid. That's why `insert` returns an iterator. Your code should be

```
iter = newVector.insert(iter, 5);
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.